# Python . Регулярное выражение при указании начала и конца строки не работает

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
import re
strng="abcABC123"
def lowercase_count(strng):
    print(re.findall('^[a-z]$', strng))
```

почему если здесь поставить Начало строки ^ и конец $ он ничего не находит? А если их убрать оно  как надо находит строчные буквы

задача — подсчитать общее количество строчных букв в строке. Я потом это в len() оберну, не проблема, просто не понятно.То есть '^[a-z]$' означает всего одну букву ? А если хочу искать из огромной строки строчные буквы почему нельзя ^ и $?

Comment: Потому что под ваш шаблон попадет только строка состоящая из одно латинской буквы в нижнем регистре. Ваш стринг выглядит так `^abcABC123$` а нужен `^a$` что бы попал под захват. Опишите какую цель преследует ваше регулярное выражение и возможно кто-то сможет вам помочь

Comment: Да никакой собственно цели  нет, упражняюсь просто .  задача — подсчитать общее количество строчных букв в строке. Я потом это в len() оберну, не проблема, просто не понятно.То есть '^[a-z]$' означает всего одну букву ? А если хочу искать из огромной строки строчные буквы почему нельзя ^ и $?

Comment: Попробую сейчас ответом объяснить

Comment: @ipatev_nn спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```txt
strng="abcABC123"
______^_________$ - определение в строке положения метасимволов начала и конца строки
```

Перевести регулярное выражение в читаемый вид:

```txt
^[a-z]$
^________ - начало строки
_^^^^^___ - буква латинского языка в нижнем регистре
______^__ - конец строки
```

Под выражение попадет только одна буква находящаяся в строке, так как границы имею четкую привязанность.

```txt
string="a"
_______^_$
```

Для примера указать только символ начала строки в выражении `^[a-z]` то регулярное выражение найдет из обоих примеров string только первую `a`

```txt
strng="abcABC123"
______^__________ - начало строки
_______^_________ - [a-z]
```

Так как нет ограничения что далее идет конец строки, то будет выбрана только первая буква в нижнем регистре находящаяся в начале строки.

`[a-z]` без указания границ строки в сочетании с `findall`(своеобразный аналог глобального поиска) осуществляет поиск всех одиночных символов латинского алфавита в нижнем регистре:

```txt
strng="abcABC123"
_______^_________ - 1 совпадение
________^________ - 2 совпадение
_________^_______ - 3 совпадение
__________^^^^^^_ - так же проверяются, но данные под захват не подходят.
```

Поиск одиночных выполняется по порядку слева на право и захватывает символы подходящие под шаблон из любого места

Comment: Спасибо за такое объяснение.  То есть если [a-z] то много символов в строке ищется, а если ^[a-z]$  то один без явного указания (например {4,16} ) ? Или до первого совпадение?

Comment: `[a-z]` эквивалентно `[a-z]{1}` т.е. это единичный символ из шаблона, существуют модификаторы регулярных выражений, в некоторых языках они отличаются, `g` - глобальный поиск по всей строке, если без глобального модификатора, то при выражение `[a-z]` будет найден первый символ с левой стороны подходящий под выражение.

Comment: Спасибо большое,  все по полочкам разложили, расставили, спасибо Вам огромное

Answer (score 1):

В `^[a-z]$`:

- `^` - означает начало строки
- `$` - означает конец строки
- `[a-z]` - означает поиск одного символа из диапазона `а` - `z`

Если хотите искать последовательности букв английского алфавита, которые могут находиться в любом месте строки, то:

```
[a-z]+
```

**PS.**

Для поиска букв в верхнем регистре используйте еще `A-Z`: `[a-zA-Z]+`. Либо в `findall` передавайте флаг [re.I или re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I)

Comment: Я не могу понять почему при ^[a-z]$ ничего не находится, а при '[a-z]' всё работает как по маслу?

Comment: @РусланКамов Потому что вы никакого квантификатора для **количества** символов не указали. Вы ищете начало строки -> 1 символ -> конец строки. А у вас не один символ в строке, а много.